# oracle sql show sums when higher than 5

Tags: sql, oracle

I,ve following data.

```
select 1 id, 3 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 2 id, 2 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 3 id, 1 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 4 id, 4 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 5 id, 7 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 6 id, 1 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 7 id, 2 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 8 id, 10 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 9 id, 3 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 10 id, 4 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 11 id, 2 amount from dual  UNION ALL
select 12 id, 4 amount from dual  UNION ALL
select 13 id, 8 amount from dual
```

I need calculate  a sum of amount. When it reaches 5 it must reset.And total of previous amounts must be showed in new column. I need a solution using only oracle sql.

Excepted result is :

[image]

Comment: What is your Oracle database version? As reported by `select banner from v$version`?

Comment: Also, what do you need to do at the end of the table, if the last few rows add up to less than 5? Just show 0 in the new column for those rows?

Comment: I have no example to provide yet, but i am pretty sure that something can be done with lead()/lag() functions. I also guess we have to assume the data have to ordered by id.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to solve this problem. I will provide a solution using oracle [Model](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/sqlmodel.htm) clause.

```
with data as (
select 1 id, 3 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 2 id, 2 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 3 id, 1 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 4 id, 4 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 5 id, 7 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 6 id, 1 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 7 id, 2 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 8 id, 10 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 9 id, 3 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 10 id, 4 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 11 id, 2 amount from dual  UNION ALL
select 12 id, 4 amount from dual  UNION ALL
select 13 id, 8 amount from dual
)

select id,amount,case when depletion<=5 then 0 else depletion end depletions from data

model  ignore nav
  dimension by (id)
  measures ( amount, 0  depletion  )
  rules  
  (
    depletion[ANY] = case when depletion[cv()-1]>5 then 0 else depletion[cv()-1] end  +amount[cv()]
  )
```

Comment: . . There are not "many" ways to solve this.  The only alternatives I can think of is a recursive CTE or hierarchical query, which would probably have much worse performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it cannot be solved using hierarchical queries because `connect by`  (unlike recursive subquery factoring) does not allow cumulative calculations. However, pattern matching is the best solution in this case.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - As Stew Ashton showed on his blog, recursive CTE is generally faster than the MODEL clause for the same job - often by an order of magnitude. And, of course, you are forgetting MATCH_RECOGNIZE (which has been illustrated in other answers already).

Comment: Could also use a cursor to loop through the rows.

Answer (score 3):

There is probably no practical reason not to use the `MODEL` clause that has already been described.  But for what it's worth, the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` feature can also accomplish the goal of grouping by a running total.

*It was commented below than `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` is faster than `MODEL`, but I have not verified that myself.*

```
select id, amount, case when cls = 'EM' THEN group_total ELSE 0 END depletions
from input
match_recognize (
  order by id
  measures
    sum(amount) as group_total,
    classifier() as cls
    all rows per match
    -- without this next line, incomplete groups (sum <= 5) will be omitted
    with unmatched rows  -- thanks @mathguy for the addition
    pattern ( grp* em ) 
    define 
      grp as sum(amount) <= 5,
      em as sum(amount) > 5
  )
order by id;
```

It works by defining your groups as a pattern of zero or more rows that have a running total <= 5 followed by a row where the running sum is > 5.

It then prints out the running sum for only the last row in each group.

Results, using the test data from OP:

> ```
> +----+--------+------------+
> | ID | AMOUNT | DEPLETIONS |
> +----+--------+------------+
> |  1 |      3 |          0 |
> |  2 |      2 |          0 |
> |  3 |      1 |          6 |
> |  4 |      4 |          0 |
> |  5 |      7 |         11 |
> |  6 |      1 |          0 |
> |  7 |      2 |          0 |
> |  8 |     10 |         13 |
> |  9 |      3 |          0 |
> | 10 |      4 |          7 |
> | 11 |      2 |          0 |
> | 12 |      4 |          6 |
> | 13 |      8 |          8 |
> +----+--------+------------+
> ```

Comment: A couple of comments regarding your solution: 1. no need for rule for second variable in a pattern 2. no need for case expression and classifier `match_recognize (order by id measures nvl(nvl(sum(x.amount),0)+y.amount,0) depletions all rows per match pattern (x* y) define x as sum(x.amount) <= 5)`

Comment: And what is the most important, there is very strong reason to use this solution instead of `model clause` - *performance*. Pattern matching requires less CPU and much more scalable then model. Deep comparison and additional details can be found here https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484233719

Comment: @DrYWit Thanks!  I look forward to reading that.  I've seen both ways regarding which is faster between `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` and `MODEL`.  I never ran any tests though, as both have always been fine for the data volumes I've used them with.  Thanks again for the link.

Comment: This solution will not cover the case when there are a few orphaned rows at the end, after the last full match (rows that sum up to less than 5). To fix that, you must use the WITH UNMATCHED ROWS option, or else make the last row (em) optional in the PATTERN clause.

Comment: @mathguy I thought about that, but then decided the OP wasn't really clear on what the requirement would be in that situation.  It's a very helpful point though, thank you.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one other solution which uses that `amount > 0`, so the distance between 2 depletions can be 5 at most:

```
with data as (select 1 id, 3 amount from dual UNION ALL
              select 2 id, 2 amount from dual UNION ALL
              select 3 id, 1 amount from dual UNION ALL
              select 4 id, 4 amount from dual UNION ALL
              select 5 id, 7 amount from dual UNION ALL
              select 6 id, 1 amount from dual UNION ALL
              select 7 id, 2 amount from dual UNION ALL
              select 8 id, 10 amount from dual UNION ALL
              select 9 id, 3 amount from dual UNION ALL
              select 10 id, 4 amount from dual UNION ALL
              select 11 id, 2 amount from dual  UNION ALL
              select 12 id, 4 amount from dual  UNION ALL
              select 13 id, 8 amount from dual
              )
, part_sum AS (SELECT a.id, b.id id2
                    , SUM(b.amount) over (PARTITION BY a.id
                                          ORDER BY b.id
                                          ROWS unbounded preceding) amount 
                 FROM DATA A
                 JOIN DATA b
                   ON b.id between a.id AND a.id+5)
, mind AS (SELECT id, MIN(id2) id2, MIN(amount) amount
             FROM part_sum 
            WHERE amount > 5
            GROUP BY id) 
, depl AS (SELECT id2, amount
             FROM mind
            START WITH id = 1
            CONNECT BY id = PRIOR id2 + 1)  
SELECT a.id, a.amount, NVL(d.amount,0) depletions
  FROM DATA a
  LEFT JOIN depl d
    ON d.id2 = a.id
ORDER BY 1
```

The view `part_sum` selects all possible combinations of id that are possible as for the positions of the depletion and sums the amount between the ids.

Then the view `mind` picks the minimum of those possible combination, getting for each id the next position of the depletion and the value to display.

Then we make hierarchical query getting all depletion points starting at id 1.

Finally left join these depletion points to the base table and default all other values for depletion to 0.

If the id is not dense or there are records with `amount = 0` you have to add one additional step:

```
SELECT id, amount, row_number() over (order by id) rn
  FROM data
 WHERE amount > 0
```

and then work with rn instead of id.

Answer (score 1):

-- have much worse performance. --

```
with data as (
select 1 id, 3 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 2 id, 2 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 3 id, 1 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 4 id, 4 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 5 id, 7 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 6 id, 1 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 7 id, 2 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 8 id, 10 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 9 id, 3 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 10 id, 4 amount from dual UNION ALL
select 11 id, 2 amount from dual  UNION ALL
select 12 id, 4 amount from dual  UNION ALL
select 13 id, 8 amount from dual
)
, rec(id, parent_id, amount, prev_amount, result_sum)
  AS (
       SELECT id
            , NULL as parent_id
            , amount
            , CASE
                WHEN amount > 5 
                THEN
                  0 
                ELSE
                  amount
              END
                AS prev_amount
            , CASE
                WHEN amount > 5 
                THEN
                  amount 
                ELSE
                  0
              END
                AS result_sum
         FROM data
        WHERE data.id = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT data.id
             , rec.id As parent_id
             , data.amount
             , CASE
                 WHEN data.amount + rec.prev_amount > 5 
                 THEN
                   0
                 ELSE
                   data.amount + rec.prev_amount
               END
                 AS prev_amount
             , CASE
                 WHEN data.amount + rec.prev_amount > 5
                 THEN
                   data.amount + rec.prev_amount
                 ELSE
                   0  
               END 
                 AS result_sum
          FROM rec
             , data
         WHERE data.id = rec.id + 1
     )
SELECT * from rec
```

Sorry for my poor English, it is not my native language.

The first part – alias of subquery named "data", in real application will some ordered list of row, and in this case we need a sort criteria. In this example – it is ID column.
Using ID column we can get rows one by one, like nodes of long tree branch.

A recursive query is used to emulate a row hierarchy in which there is only one long branch without branching, from the root (ID = 1) to the last node (ID = 13).

A recursive query consists of two subqueries.

In the first, a row with ID = 1 is added to the result (beginning of recursion).

The second subquery reads the remaining rows recursively. For each subsequent row, the required conditions are checked:

if 
        data.amount (value of the amount column of the current row) 
     + rec.prev_amount (value of the prev_amount column of the previous row) > 5 
then
 1. the value of amount column of current row must be data.amount + rec.prev_amount.
 2. Next row should start counting from zero.

If data.amount + rec.prev_amount <= 5, then

1. For the current row the value of amount column must be 0
2. Next row should take into account the value of prev_amount of the current row

Comment: Could you explain why you this answer provides a solution?

Comment: There is no need to calculate two columns in rec with: prev_amount, result_sum. You can simply calculate running sum and display calculated value as `0` if it does not exceed 5.